How to write the objective function that involves squart root and inverse function in cplex opl
I want to optimize a problem in which the objective contains the square root and inverse of a variable.
I tried writing like this:
using CP;
dvar int+ y;
dvar int+ z;
minimize z;
subject to{
  z==4/sqrt(2+y);
  y>=1;
  y<=4;
} 

This problem is fine. But my decision variables are float type. When I include the float-type decision variables, I get an error.

You can use dexpr float as can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod
using CP;

int nbKids=310;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
int scale=100;

 
dvar int+ scalenbBus40;
dvar int+ scalenbBus30;

dexpr float nbBus40=scalenbBus40/scale;
dexpr float nbBus30=scalenbBus30/scale;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
  writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40);
  writeln("nbBus30 = ",nbBus30);
}

With your example that gives
using CP;

int scale=10000;

dvar int+ scaley;


dexpr float y=scaley/scale;

dexpr float z=4/sqrt(2+y);
minimize z;
subject to{
 
  y>=1;
  y<=4;
} 

